# Square root of complex numbers - g++ vs icpc

Tags: c++, standards, complex-numbers, icc

A rather basic question but I am a little bit lost here. I am working on a library, which works with complex numbers. So far I used my implementation under Mac OS 10.8 and Ubuntu 10.04 (by using llvm-gcc on Man and gcc under Ubuntu).
Yesterday I tried it on another machine with the icpc (icc/2013.3) and the complex number crunch part failed.

I nailed the problem down by using this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::complex<double> tmpcmplxnumber(26.0,0.0);
    cout << "Number: " << tmpcmplxnumber << endl;
    std::complex<double> newcmplxnumber = 1.0 - tmpcmplxnumber;
    cout << "New Number: " << newcmplxnumber << endl;

    cout << "Sqrt of New Number: " << sqrt(newcmplxnumber) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gcc output (both machines) :

```
Number: (26,0)
New Number: (-25,-0)
Sqrt of New Number: (0,-5)
```

icpc output:

```
Number: (26,0)
New Number: (-25,0)
Sqrt of New Number: (0,5)
```

If I am informed correctly gcc implements the ISO standard, so the result should be correct (with all the signed-zero stuff ... etc) So is the icpc implementation "wrong" or is there a flag for that specific issue ?

*update*
I know that both results are valid from a mathematical point of view, however I need the gcc result also when using the icpc.

Comment: They're both correct. The square root of any number has two solutions, positive and negative.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "either" is necessarily more right than the other, but how about using `abs` to fix up the sign?

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` is normally the non-negative square root, which is the one denoted by the "square root" sign in mathematics.

According to the (draft) Standard (26.4.8, *complex transcendentals*),

> If the argument is a negative real number, the value returned lies on
>   the positive imaginary axis.

so it looks like gcc is at fault here.

Comment: Yeah but I got a sqrt of a complex number (nevertheless the imaginary part is 0) and shouldn´t icpc change the sign of the imaginary part as well (Second line) ?

Comment: @Stoiker A complex number with a zero imaginary part *is* a real number. And the `-0` from gcc looks very strange to me.